# Cannot set UltraGrid Checkbox value to True after saving the initial data

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, infragistics, ultrawingrid

My project contains a form which allows the entering of orders, using an `UltraGrid`.

One column is a `checkbox` style column, to represent whether or not the order has been delivered.

When the order reaches 'Stage 4 - Awaiting Goods Delivery', the user can set the column value to `True`, which in turn prompts a new window, to allow the user to enter the volume and value of the delivery.
If the order hasn't been fully delivered, the `checkbox` is set back to `False`, and the order line turns yellow (Eg; 5 gates have been ordered, but only 3 delivered = `False`, but a yellow order line).

After saving the order, closing it and going back into it, I'm trying to set the `Checkbox` to `True`, to update the order to add on the rest of the delivery (the final 2 gates have been delivered), but as soon as I set it to `True`, it instantly becomes `False` again (When stepping through the following code in the `CellChange` method, it says the cell value is `False` too).

So, why can I only change the value once? After it's been saved, why can the value then not be changed again? Is it do with the fact that it's saved as `False` in the database?

```
Try
  If e.Cell.Column.ToString = "Goods_Delivered" Then
     e.Cell.Row.Update()

       If e.Cell.Value = True Then
           If IsDBNull(e.Cell.Row.Cells("Final_Delivery").Value) Then
              MsgBox("Please enter a delivery date", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Date")
                    e.Cell.Row.Cells("Goods_Delivered").Value = False
           Else
            Dim f As New dlgDelivery(e.Cell.Row, Me, e.Cell.Row.Cells("Final_Delivery").Value, con, orderNumber, e.Cell.Row.Cells("Product_Code").Value, exTotal)
                f.ShowDialog()
           End If

           e.Cell.Row.Update()

        cmdCheck_Click(sender, New EventArgs)
        cmdTotals_Click(sender, New EventArgs)

  ElseIf e.Cell.Value = False Then
      ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Final_Delivery").Value = DBNull.Value
       productCode = ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Product_Code").Value
       database.NotDelivered(orderNumber, productCode, con)
     Exit Sub
  Else
  End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error within this was with `e.Row.Update()`.

I was committing the value of the cell and then you are SETTING the value of the cell, which was causing `CellChange` to fire again recursively, and after that I'm not sure what happens, but there was more effective ways of writing this code.

```
Try
  If e.Cell.Column.Key = "Goods_Delivered" Then
   Dim goodsDelivered As Boolean = Boolean.Parse(e.Cell.Text)
     If goodsDelivered = True Then
      If IsDBNull(e.Cell.Row.Cells("Final_Delivery").Value) Then
       MsgBox("Please enter a delivery date", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Date")
       Dim checkEditor As CheckEditor = e.Cell.EditorResolved
       checkEditor.Value = False
      Else
       Dim f As New dlgDelivery(e.Cell.Row, Me, e.Cell.Row.Cells("Final_Delivery").Value, con, orderNumber, e.Cell.Row.Cells("Product_Code").Value, exTotal)
       f.ShowDialog()
      End If
     ElseIf goodsDelivered = False Then
       ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Final_Delivery").Value = DBNull.Value
                productCode = ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Product_Code").Value
                database.NotDelivered(orderNumber, productCode, con)
             Exit Sub
         End If
      End If

Catch ex As Exception
   errorLog(ex)

 End Try
```